# xargs and git issues in windows powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, git, grep, xargs

I've been using the following command to delete any merged git branches:

`git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "master" | grep -v "staging" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d`

`grep` and `xargs` both being packaged with git for windows. Recently moved computers and decided to switch to powershell (from windows cmd) adn this no longer works as expected. Instead of deleting the branch I get (note the question mark at the end):

`error: branch '<branch-name>?' not found.`

The strange thing as that changing the command to the following prints without questionmarks:
`git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -v "master" | grep -v "staging" | xargs -n 1 echo`

and manually deleting the branch using `git branch -d` also works without an issue. I'm curious where the question mark is coming from and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Running external commands in PS is a regular thing and well documented all over the web as is Git with PS over the web --- Search ['powershell running executables'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20running%20executables%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20running%20executables%27&sc=3-32&sk=&cvid=525835229A7A4173908EEA3C7B01E7FD) and  ['PowerShell using git'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell+using+git%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=d5d76b27ddcf459687a6bc759ce9f807&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell+using+g%27&sc=3-20&qs=n&sk=&cvid=d5d76b27ddcf459687a6bc759ce9f807)

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you are new to PowerShell, and that is fine, but you should spend some time learning it first to avoid confusion, misunderstanding, mistakes, bad assumptions, unneeded errors, etc. Youtube has many videos to learn from.

PowerShell has modules for Git that you can use from PowerShell consolehost, the PowerShell ISE, and VSCode. Powershell is hosted on GitHub.

There are modules you can download and install for use with git/Github.

```
Find-Module -Name '*git*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
 Find-Module -Name '*git*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

Version     Name                                        Repository Description                                                     
-------     ----                                        ---------- -----------                                                     
0.7.3       posh-git                                    PSGallery  Provides prompt with Git status summary information and tab c...
0.14.0      PowerShellForGitHub                         PSGallery  PowerShell wrapper for GitHub API                               
1.3.8       GitLabProvider                              PSGallery  GitLab PackageManagement provider                               
1.4.1       Git                                         PSGallery  Common Git cmdlets                                              
1.4.0       InstallModuleFromGitHub                     PSGallery  PowerShell module that installs modules from GitHub             
0.5         GitHubProvider                              PSGallery  GitHub-as-a-Package - PackageManagement PowerShell Provider t...
0.1.0.0     ISEGit                                      PSGallery  Module to work with git in PowerShell ISE. Configured using d...
...
#>
```

Also when running internal and external commands, there are special considerations that you must learn and how to use them. For example special characters, reserved words/tokens, and aliases.

> [about_Special_Characters - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters)
>
> [about_Reserved_Words - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_reserved_words)
>
> [PowerShell - Special Characters And Tokens](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens)
>
> [About_Aliases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=%20PowerShell%20includes%20the%20following%20cmdlets%2C%20which%20are,Imports%20an%20alias%20file%20into%20PowerShell.%20More%20)

You also need to understand command precedence.

> [about_Command_Precedence - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence)

See also:

> [Make Powershell, SSH Github and Git Suck Less on Windows](http://learnaholic.me/2012/10/12/make-powershell-and-git-suck-less-on-windows)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933964/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-git-into-the-windows-cmd-or-powershell
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428949/whats-the-equivalent-of-xargs-in-powershell
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794516/convert-xargs-bash-command-to-powershell

There are several ways to run external commands. The most common one is:

> [5. The Call Operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing
> with spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another
> command that starts with a number, you have to use the command
> invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case, you don’t
> need the & anymore.
>
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator,
> also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that
> are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call
> operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command
> parameters

```
# Example:

& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters
> or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
> With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear!
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
 
# or same like that:
 
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
 
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

Comment: Although you're right about that there are packages for that, the fact that Windows is not POSIX compliant remains, and PowerShell, how much portable it is, relies on the host and does not polyfill POSIX interfaces, unlike something like mingw.